Meaning of verb-ものも-verb-neg pattern

お前たち二人がバカ騒ぎしてくれたおかげで、もう捕まるものも捕まらんかもしれん。 (Harry Potter Japanese TL)
Thanks to you two messing around we might not catch it now  (my translation)

I haven't seen this verb-ものも-verb-neg pattern before. If I had to guess I'd say it expanded to something like "We might not catch it now even if there was originally some chance of catching it". Is this anywhere near right?
Could you please give a few more examples of using this structure?

Yes, you're on the right track. The literal translation would be "we won't catch even ones we would catch", and this pattern expresses regret or irony about something making things impossible.
Similar examples:

それでは助かるものも助からなくなる。
That way, even those who could be saved won't be saved.
そんな治療をすれば治るものも治らないだろう。
値段が高すぎると売れるものも売れなくなってしまいます。

